# Data transfer from one java file to another activity.java in android

Tags: android, android-activity, data-transfer

In android, how can i transfer values from xyz.java to main_activity.java......providee that xyz.java is a simple java class and doesn't belong to any activity. I am working with an api , when i run it as simple .java file it is working fine bit not with activity file.?.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean saying " when i run it as simple .java file it is working fine bit not with activity file"

Comment: There is a simple java file and the default activity_main.java file.I need to transfer data from simple java file to activity_main.java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the xyz.java class in your main_activity.java like :

```
xyz xyzInstance = new xyz();
```

You can then access the public methods and attributes of xyz class using

```
int x = xyzInstance.value;
```

You can also make the values inside xyz class static and directly access the values like :

```
int x = xyz.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to create Xyz.java class object like this:

**Main_Activity.java**

```
Xyz x=new Xyz();

//use x object to get values from xyz class

int value=x.mydata;
```

***Xyz.java***

```
class Xyz

{

public int mydata=10;

}
```